# Insert function using templates loses number

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

Hey guys I just have a small problem. When I insert numbers into my Ordered list, everyone of them shows up except the last one I insert. The count variable I have shows that, for now, all 6 are in there. But when I print the list, the last one is missing. Any help with be appreciated. Time is of the essence as its due at 11:00PM

Insert function for Ordered List:

```
template <class T>
void OListType<T>::insert (const T& item) {
 NodeType<T> *curr=this->head, *prev=NULL;
 while (curr!=NULL && curr->item<item) {
     prev = curr;
     curr = curr->next;
 }
 if (prev==NULL) {
     this->head = new NodeType<T>;
     this->head->item=item;
     this->head->next=curr;
  }
 else{
     prev->next=new NodeType<T>;
     prev->next->item=item;
     prev->next->next=curr;
 }
 ++this->count;
}
```

Main Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ListType.h"
#include "UListType.h"
#include "OListType.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
 OListType<int> OList_int;
 UListType<int> UList_int;

 OList_int.insert(45);
 OList_int.insert(100);
 OList_int.insert(7);
 OList_int.insert(83);
 OList_int.insert(29);
 OList_int.insert(49);

 cout<< "The Ordered List size after inserts: ";
 cout<< OList_int.size() << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Ordered List values after inserts: ";
 cout << OList_int << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Ostream Overload Code:

```
template <class U>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const ListType<U> &list) {
 if (!list.empty()) {
   NodeType<U> *temp=list.head->next;
   out << list.head->item;
   temp=temp->next;
   while(temp!=NULL) {
     out << "," << temp->item;
     temp=temp->next;
   }
 }
 return out;
}
```

If you need any more of the code, I'll provide it.

Comment: Your insert() seems fine.  Can you add your "operator <<(std::ostream)" code please?

Comment: okay I added it. tell me what you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class U>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const ListType<U> &list) {
if (list.head) {
 NodeType<U> *temp=list.head;
 out << list.head->item;
 temp=temp->next;
 while(temp!=NULL) {
 out << "," << temp->item;
 temp=temp->next;
 }
}
return out;
}
```

have made the following change NodeType *temp=list.head; :)